# how to pass layout for ember modal box in ember 2.8

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In ember 1.8 views was not deprecated so i had pass view as layout for ember modal box.

Recently i have upgraded to ember 2.8.3. and view is not supported.

```
actions: { 
    showModal: function (name, content) {
        ModalContext.setProperties({"name":name});
        this.controllerFor(name).set('content', content); 
        this.render(name, { 
            into: 'application',
            outlet: 'modal',
            view:'common/modal' 
        }); 
     } 
}
```

How to set layout for modal-box.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [Ember.View](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html) should be replaced by [Component](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html).
You can [ember-elsewhere](https://github.com/ef4/ember-elsewhere) addon to show modal

Comment: Thanks @kumkanillam for response.